# Is there any character length limitation for HTML5 title tooltip in IE9 and chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, tooltip

For table data i have its content as its title content(very long multiple line text).In case of IE9 the tooltip doesn't show full text while Chrome displays tootltip with full text.I am using HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amit,

Few points,

1. I am not sure if IE9 supports HTML5 (refer [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29)
2. I am not sure if Title attribute is different in HTML5 and HTML4.01
3. In HTML 4.01, the title attribute length in IE is restricted to 512
   (refer
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/ms534683(v=vs.85)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/ms534683%28v=vs.85%29))

Hope that helps and sorry if I have misunderstood your question :-)

-Milind

Comment: Thanks for your answer.You are indeed correct HTML 4.0.1 restricts character length to 512.I was not sure if same applies to HTML5 as well.

Comment: 1. IE9 does support HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

1. As for IE9 the restriction of 512 characters in HTML 4.1 still holds true for HTML5. Anything beyond 512 chars will get truncated.
2. For chrome, there is no such restriction.